# How to create generic docker images without specific parameters

Tags: azure, docker, containers, camunda

I use a workflow engine called Camunda with a docker image, this tool connects to an Azure SQL instance and I created the image with the code below (removed some info for security purposes).

Then I pushed the image to Azure Container Registry and it works perfect for our DEV environment.

However I would like to use the same image for our Staging and Production Environment.

How can I remove the connection string settins from the docker file with variables and then replace those variables at deployment time?

```
FROM alpine:3.10 as builder

ARG VERSION=7.12.0
ARG DISTRO=tomcat
ARG SNAPSHOT=true

ARG EE=false
ARG USER
ARG PASSWORD

RUN apk add --no-cache \
        ca-certificates \
        maven \
        tar \
        wget \
        xmlstarlet

COPY settings.xml download.sh camunda-tomcat.sh camunda-wildfly.sh  /tmp/

RUN /tmp/download.sh

#Enable Basic AUTH
COPY web.xml /camunda/webapps/engine-rest/WEB-INF/web.xml 

##### FINAL IMAGE #####

FROM alpine:3.10

ARG VERSION=7.12.0



ENV CAMUNDA_VERSION=${VERSION}
ENV DB_DRIVER=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
ENV DB_URL=jdbc:sqlserver://servername.database.windows.net:1433;database=abc;user=username@servername;password={bcd};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
ENV DB_USERNAME=username@servername
ENV DB_PASSWORD=bcd
ENV DB_CONN_MAXACTIVE=20
ENV DB_CONN_MINIDLE=5
ENV DB_CONN_MAXIDLE=20
ENV DB_VALIDATE_ON_BORROW=true
ENV DB_VALIDATION_QUERY="SELECT 1"
ENV SKIP_DB_CONFIG=
ENV WAIT_FOR=
ENV WAIT_FOR_TIMEOUT=120
ENV TZ=UTC
ENV DEBUG=TRUE
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx768m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"

EXPOSE 8080 8000

# Downgrading wait-for-it is necessary until this PR is merged
# https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/pull/68
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        bash \
        ca-certificates \
        openjdk11-jre-headless \
        tzdata \
        tini \
        xmlstarlet \
    && wget -O  /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh \
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/a454892f3c2ebbc22bd15e446415b8fcb7c1cfa4/wait-for-it.sh" --no-check-certificate \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh

RUN addgroup -g 1000 -S camunda && \
    adduser -u 1000 -S camunda -G camunda -h /camunda -s /bin/bash -D camunda
WORKDIR /camunda
USER camunda

#MSSQL SERVER JDBC DRIVER INSTALL
COPY mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre11.jar /camunda/lib/


ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]
CMD ["./camunda.sh"]

COPY --chown=camunda:camunda --from=builder /camunda .
```